# TextView consumes onTouchEvent

Tags: android, textview, viewgroup

For a custom layout, I need to monitor `TouchEvents` using the `onInterceptTouchEvent` method of the `ViewGroup`. I have the following layout inside a `ViewGroup`.

```
<RelativeLayout
   ...
   ...
   ...
    <TextView>
   ...
    <ImageView>
   ...
    <WebView>
   ...
   ...
RelativeLayout>
```

I am facing problem with monitoring events when the touch is over the `TextView`. It seems `TextView` is consuming the event. I do see the first `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` event in `onInterceptTouchEvent` method, but subsequent `MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE` & `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP` are not received.

`TextView` is only showing static text content. What could be at play here and  is there a way to ensure that the `TextView` does not consume the touch event ?

Comment: what do you return in onInterceptTouchEvent?

Comment: onInterceptTouchEvent returns false.

Comment: so if you don't steal the event it will be propagated down to child views

Comment: I mentioned, I need to passively monitor the touch events. The problem is that TextView is consuming the event when it is not doing anything with the event.

Comment: how do you know it's a TextView?

Comment: Its only when you touch over the textview, do I face this issue. touching over WebView or ImageView works fine.

Comment: wait, you have a FrameLayout so all the children are stacked one over another?

Comment: @pskink I have updated the question. It is RelativeLayout and not FrameLayout as I wrote earlier.

Comment: tried to debug TextView.onTouchEvent?  maybe its "clickable" or something?